# NFC　おサイフケータイ　パスワード　解除

Tags: android

こんにちは

この間Samsung galaxy A20を新規購入しました。
おサイフケータイ機能があります。
いつもはスイカカードをスマホの後ろに貼っています。改札口でかざすとICカードが読まれてます。
昨日ついスイカモバイルをインストールしてしまって削除／退会しましたが改札口でICカードの代わりに携帯のスイカが読まれます。結局通れなかった。
いろいろ調べておサイフケータイ機能をLockしたら読まれないようになりますがLockのパスワードは面倒なことです。
モバイルスイカよりスイカカードを別々使いたいので面倒なく簡単な方法を教えてほしいです。
携帯の設定メニューの中でおサイフケータイロックのパスワードを削除メニューがないのでもっと簡単な方法を考えています。
タッチでオン／オフできるとか。。。
私は少しAndroidのプログラミングできますのでプログラミングとかでNFCのロックができるかどうかを聞きたいです。
またロックのパスワードも削除したいのでわかる方は是非教えてください。

よろしくお願いいたします。
p/s: 新人で nfc や osaifu-keitai タグをつけられないのでできる方は助けてください。

Comment: おそらくですが、質問内容のことをプログラミングによって解決するのは困難(不可能？)な気がします。ちなみに最近の機種では画面ロックとICロックが連動するものもありますが、把握してる限り一部のXperiaとPixelシリーズなどでありそもそも搭載チップに差異があるようです。なお、交通系のサービスコードがおサイフケータイに残っているのでこの事象が発生するとしたとき、キャリアショップでおサイフケータイの丸々のリセットが可能であったりするので一度リセットするのも手かもしれません。(他におサイフケータイを利用している場合は引継ぎ操作が必要になるかもしれませんが。)

Comment: コメントありがとう御座います。SAMSUNGA20ーAndroid9の場合は画面ロックとICロックが違うものです。ロックON/OFFする時はPW入力しかないので操作も面倒です。
ビックカメラでUIモバイルと契約していますがリセットしてくれるかどうか不明ですが一度行って見ます。プログラミングで出来たら一番素敵ですね。